# Spotlight Search displays "Indexing..." forever

Tags: macos, spotlight

macOS 10.12.6

Spotlight Search, when I start to type, it changes from a single-line text field to the real-time search results.

In the left, between the bar and the "Top Hits" search results, it says "Indexing..." and displays a full horizontal bar.

This never advances (it looks full), and it never finishes.

The search results are not correct since this started happening.

I was suffering from the Safari 12 -> Spotlight Search display disappears while typing problem, and I've turned off the Safari indexing already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "never", how long? Indexing can take hours on a large mechanical hard drive. This is usually required after an OS update.

You can restart and rebuild the Spotlight index, which may help. Either use the Terminal command:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

*(You'll then have to enter your admin password. If you've never done this before, you'll see a short warning about being careful.)*

Or go to System Preferences > Spotlight, and in the Privacy tab, drag the system volume to the list of exclusions. Then remove it.

Hanging Spotlight indexes may also be a sign of a failing hard drive, so it's also worth checking that your system volume is functioning correctly.

Comment: Re "forever": I have a 128GB SSD, and its been like this for about 2 weeks. The computer is plugged in and on for about half the day, so I think it's had enough time to try to finish. I'll try your terminal command and update here...

Comment: It returns: `Indexing enabled. `

Comment: Yes. But it will delete the old index and start again.

Comment: command line didn't change the problem described, so I am trying the UI steps you provided.

Comment: I'd verify the drive, if I were you.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, because I think future readers will find this is the best advice. In my specific case, my Mac is heavily loaded, and I was too busy to reboot it. My (unproven) suspicion is that it needed to be rebooted to recover from the last security update, several process d's were constantly asking for passwords as well.